# Are there any .NET OpenSource IMap libraries available?

Tags: imap, pop3, openpop

I'm currently using OpenPop for handling Pop3 email within my application and have found it to be very reliable. But I need to be able to support IMAP too.

I noticed there is an OpenImap library from the same author as OpenPop, but it is in pre-alpha stage so doubt it would be in a stable state. Are there any other recommended .NET open-source libraries that handle Imap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

1. http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/download/downloads/Net/
2. http://www.lumisoft.ee/lsWWW/download/downloads/Examples/
3. http://www.lumisoft.ee/forum/

Comment: Aren't these all commercial libraries?

Comment: Nope, these are open and free.